# How to write glue job script, to run all tables in aws glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-glue

Hello anyone know how to write glue job script to run all tables in glue?
Please need help in understanding how to call all database and tables in glue?

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems have you encountered? What do you mean by "call all database and tables"?

Comment: I think one possible solution is that by using boto3 in Lambda. Step 1: Get All database and table names from the lambda function and run the glue job by providing database and table name in argument.